# Change tabs in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, tabs, bootstrap-tabs

I'm new to React tabs. I have built tabs in bootstrap but the problem is, I don't know how I can open a new page when clicked on a tab.

Here is my code:

```
import { Container, Row, Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import "./Tabs.css";
import BsTab from "./BsTab";

const BsTabs = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container className="py-4">
        <Row className="justify-content-center">
          <Tabs
            justify
            variant="pills"
            defaultActiveKey="home"
            className="mb-1 p=0"
          >
            <Tab eventKey="kurye Tasimasi" title="Kurye Tasimasi">
              <BsTab />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="Hava Yolu Tasimasi" title="Hava Yolu Tasimasi">
              <BsTab />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="Deniz Yolu Tasimasi " title="Deniz Yolu Tasimasi">
              <BsTab />
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BsTabs;
```

So basically, what I want is to open a new page when clicked on one of the tabs.

Comment: do you like open link in the new tab?

Comment: @PallamollaSai yes it could be

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open new pages when user click the tab, then why don't you just use links with target="_blank" instead of the Tabs/Tab modules?

Comment: I have tried this way but it didnt work for me 

    <Tab eventKey="kurye Tasimasi" title="Kurye Tasimasi">
              <a href="./BsTab" target="_blank">
        
                Kurye Tasimasi
              </a>
            </Tab>

Comment: would u please explain ur answer a bit more?

Comment: If you use a hyperlink <a> and style it like a tab, wouldn't that work?

Comment: it would work but after clicking on the button it would redirect me to the same page

Comment: But you have to include href="/target_page"
If you want to open a new window/tab, then you need to use target="_blank"

Comment: this is what u used   <a href="./BsTab" target="_blank">
            {" "}
            HEY YOU!
          </a>

Comment: so you want to open the content of the clicked tab in the new opened page?
If so, then you need to provide something that tells the new loaded page to switch to the tab. This usually depends on the tab plugin that you are using.

Usually it's something like href="./BsTab#tab2"

Answer (score 0):

You need to map each tab with the required URL. Have a look at the following pen:
[React tabs](https://codepen.io/AdamMorsi/pen/KYaoZO)

```
const Tabs = ({ activeTab, tabsList, isFancyTabs = true }) => {
  const history = useHistory(),
    [isUrlTabs, setIsUrlTabs] = useState(false),
    [currentActiveTab, setCurrentActiveTab] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tabsList.find((el) => el.tabUrl)) {
      setIsUrlTabs(true);
    } else {
      if (activeTab !== 0 && activeTab && activeTab < tabsList.length) {
        setCurrentActiveTab(activeTab);
      } else {
        setCurrentActiveTab(0);
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUrlTabs) {
      const currentActiveTabUrlIndex = tabsList.findIndex(
        (el) => el.tabUrl === history.location.pathname
      );
      setCurrentActiveTab(
        currentActiveTabUrlIndex !== -1 ? currentActiveTabUrlIndex : 0
      );
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [history.location.pathname, isUrlTabs]);

  const onChangeTab = (index, tabUrl) => {
    if (tabUrl) history.push(tabUrl);
    else setCurrentActiveTab(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className="tabs">
      <div
        className={`${isFancyTabs ? "fancy-labels-wrapper" : "labels-wrapper"}`}
      >
        <ConditionalWrapper
          initialWrapper={(children) => <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>}
          wrapper={(children) => <div className="labels">{children}</div>}
          condition={isFancyTabs}
        >
          {tabsList.map((el, i) => (
            <div
              className={
                "tab-label" +
                (currentActiveTab === i ? " active-tab-label" : "")
              }
              key={i}
              onClick={() => {
                onChangeTab(i, el.tabUrl);
              }}
            >
              {el.label}
            </div>
          ))}
        </ConditionalWrapper>
      </div>
      <div
        className="tabs-content-wrapper"
        style={{ borderRadius: isFancyTabs ? 10 : 0 }}
      >
        {tabsList.map((el, i) => (
          <div
            className={
              "tab-content" +
              (currentActiveTab === i ? " active-tab-content" : "")
            }
            key={i}
          >
            {currentActiveTab === i && el.content}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```